# AngularJS unbind after onBeforeUnload prompt, $destroy not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, event-listener, onbeforeunload

I have a requirement to show a prompt whenever our reservation page is navigated away from.  When navigating within the app, there is no problem.  A simple $onLocationChange works fine with a custom prompt.  However when navigating to , for example, google or our logout page (which is in a separate angular app) the $onLocationChange does not work.  In this case, I used:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = onUnloadAppStart;

function onUnloadAppStart() {
        var message = figureOutWhichMessageToUse();
        return message;
}
```

this way I can at least customize the navigate message, even though I cant change the prompt box itself.  However this causes a memory leak.  So I need to set to null when I leave.  Something like this:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
```

however this(the $destroy event) only seems to fire when I navigate within the app, same as the $onLocationChange.  Furthermore I need to clean up binding AFTER the prompt, which is after the onUnloadAppStart function.  This is because if I remove the binding and the user says "no, stay on this page", now my "onbeforeunload" is screwed up.  Is there a way to fire functions after the onbeforeunload prompt?

Comment: Most browsers don't allow custom message any more. Why do you say it causes memory leak?

Comment: is this not a pretty common problem in javascript?  I am watching my memory tab in dev tools. leaving and re-entering the page (leaving and re-entering the  app)cause my memory to rise, while sitting idle on the page leaves the memory the same.